# wordpress - post editor suddenly converting "<" to "&lt";. how can i avoid this situation?

Tags: html, wordpress, editor, character-entities

I have some wordpress sites in my local pc.

One day I did not see the images suddenly.

So, I checked markup and admin editor.

Site markup :

```
"<img.../>"
```

(images are not visible because surrounded by double quotes)

Admin editor : when I add images, I can see images in the editor.
but after publish click, images convert to text in the visual tab.

```
<img.../>
```

and move to the text tab, it looks like

```
&lt;img...&gt;
```

My all sites are showing the same problem.

There seems to be a problem with my computer environment.

Is it related to php.ini or other file's config?

Our team manages code through Git. Other staff didn't have any problem.

So the source code is fine and no other plugins are required.

Pls help me!

- php version: 7.1.14
- wordpress version: 4.9.7